# class Class - instance vs. class methods

Tags: ruby

How is it that this works? When the following is run `"hi from class"` is printed twice. What is going on inside ruby to make this behave like this? Am I NOT in fact making an instance method for class

```
class Class
  def foo
    puts "hi from class" 
  end
end

Class.foo
x = Class.new
x.foo
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know whether you're aware of that, but when you do `class Class ... end`, you're not creating a new class named `Class`, you're reopening the existing class `Class`.

Since `Class` is the class that all classes are instances of that means that `Class` is an instance of itself. And because of that you can call any instance methods of `Class` directly on `Class` the same way you can on any other class.

Comment: So what happens when (in the body of `class Class`) I `def self.foo; puts "hi from **self**"; end;` ... now the statement `Class.foo` prints `hi from self`?

Comment: @slindsey3000: If you define both an instance method and a class method on `Class` then `Class.foo` will call the class method and `AnyOtherClass.foo` will call the instance method. So in your example `Class.foo` will print `hi from **self**` and e.g. `String.foo` will print `hi from class`.